# Issue with JSON in android above 2.3 (Gingerbread)

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I have problems about json in android
I currently have following code from 2 classes which are JSONParser.java dan Tab1.java for login function.
this will work like charm in android 2.3.3 and below, but it not work if above it. (honeycomb, ICS, JB)
I have googling about this problem and I found that it has something to do with asynctask, but I still don't understand how to implement it in my code.
Sorry for asking newbie question, I appreciate your help
thanks before.

```
JSONParser.java

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject AmbilJson(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

here is the login class

```
Tab1.java

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Tab1 extends Activity {
    String var_usr,var_pass;
    EditText usr, psw;
    JSONArray str_login = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.panel_login);

        usr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        psw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_pass);


        Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                var_usr = usr.getText().toString();
                var_pass = psw.getText().toString();
                String stts = "";
                String kode = "";
                String link_url = "http://10.0.2.2/gollege/login.php?usr="+var_usr+"&psw="+var_pass;
                com.bucheuw.gollege.portal.JSONParser jParser = new com.bucheuw.gollege.portal.JSONParser();
                JSONObject json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);

                try {
                    str_login = json.getJSONArray("statuslogin");

                    for(int i = 0; i < str_login.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject ar = str_login.getJSONObject(i);
                        TextView st = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_alert);
                        String alrt = ar.getString("hasil");
                        stts = ar.getString("st");
                        kode = ar.getString("id");
                        st.setText(alrt);
                        usr.setText("");
                        psw.setText("");

                        if(stts.trim().equals("ok"))
                        {
                            Intent ni = null;                           
                            ni = new Intent(Tab1.this, com.bucheuw.gollege.portal.DashboardActivity.class);
                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            b.putString("par_kode", kode);
                            ni.putExtras(b);
                            startActivity(ni);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }



}
```

logcat error lines

```
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.bucheuw.gollege.portal.JSONParser.AmbilJson(JSONParser.java:38)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.bucheuw.gollege.Tab1$1.onClick(Tab1.java:51)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-21 18:25:57.016: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post the logcat error lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in later versions you cannot do a network connection in a main thread..
To use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)..

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask {

```
   private Context context;

   public MyTask(Context context) {
     this.context = context;
   }

   protected void onPreExecute() {
      progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "msg", true); 
   }

  protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
       //add here your json part
  }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     progressDialog.dismiss();

     Intent ni = null;                           
                        ni = new Intent(Tab1.this, com.bucheuw.gollege.portal.DashboardActivity.class);
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putString("par_kode", kode);
                        ni.putExtras(b);
                        startActivity(ni);  
 }
}
```

Comment: I suggest use this above code and show a ProgressDialog till it fetch data from server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that might you are facing is because of the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

From the ICS and above versions Android won't allowed any network operation in the UI thread.It should be done in separate thread so it won't hang the UI.Try your network communication code in the separate thread.